# 7 day cumulative sum that resets on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a script that counts every time a customer spends more than €1200 within 7 days. Once a customer exceeds the €1200 threshold the cumulative sum should reset. For example, if a customer exceeded €1200 on day 3 this counts as 1 and the cumulative sum should reset on day 4.

I have seen similar questions which cover a resetting cumulative sum. None of these solutions work with the 7 day rolling condition.

Example Data Set

```
create table test2
(
  yyyymmdd   DATE not null,
  account_id NUMBER,
  vol_eur    NUMBER
);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 11:16:19', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57642, 1500);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('06-01-2018 09:51:23', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57645, 190);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 07:09:35', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57645, 300);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('03-01-2018 14:58:14', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57646, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('17-01-2018 13:30:44', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57646, 130);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('03-01-2018 18:33:33', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('04-01-2018 08:44:33', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 270);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('05-01-2018 19:28:08', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 800);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('13-01-2018 12:24:21', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 700);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('15-01-2018 10:52:50', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('27-01-2018 12:07:20', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 500);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('10-01-2018 21:14:46', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 690);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('30-01-2018 15:39:17', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57647, 5500);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('05-01-2018 19:43:38', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57649, 300);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('06-01-2018 17:54:30', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57649, 150);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('15-01-2018 19:38:36', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57649, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('20-01-2018 13:26:34', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57649, 1150);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('06-01-2018 17:09:54', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57651, 300);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('28-01-2018 17:31:14', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57651, 250);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('04-01-2018 13:39:06', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57654, 150);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('07-01-2018 13:18:26', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57654, 200);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('13-01-2018 19:44:08', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57654, 150);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 16:18:05', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57654, 150);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('28-01-2018 10:53:03', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57654, 60);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('01-01-2018 12:09:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57655, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('01-01-2018 17:01:27', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57655, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('02-01-2018 19:30:31', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57655, 200);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 15:52:29', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57655, 1000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 16:58:52', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57655, 500);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('11-01-2018 14:26:30', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57661, 2000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('12-01-2018 21:54:25', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57661, 500);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('06-01-2018 16:46:25', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 5000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('10-01-2018 18:27:51', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 5000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('14-01-2018 18:52:14', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 5000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('20-01-2018 12:19:07', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 5000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('24-01-2018 18:38:40', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 2990);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('30-01-2018 18:36:01', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57666, 1980);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('19-01-2018 18:48:44', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57671, 2000);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('19-01-2018 23:41:56', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57671, 100);
insert into test2 (yyyymmdd, account_id, vol_eur)
values (to_date('21-01-2018 19:22:51', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 57671, 5000);
commit;
```

Comment: This type of logic requires a hierarchical or recursive query.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Oracle 12c.

Comment: what should the start date for the initial 7 day period be? showing the expected output would help.

Comment: The first purchase date for each customer

Comment: What do you expect as an output? In particular, if amounts for 8 consecutive days are (200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 400) thus sum from day 1 till day 7 is 1100 (thus does no exceed limit in 7 days) while sum from day 2 till day 8 is 1400 (thus exceeds limit in 7 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with a recursive cte.

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt) as rnum 
                 from tbl t
                )
,rsum as (select id,dt,val,rnum,val as cumsum,0 as dt_diff
          from rownums
          where rnum = 1
          union all
          select r.id
                ,r.dt
                ,r.val
                ,r.rnum
                ,case when dt_diff + rs.dt - r.dt > 7 then r.val
                      when dt_diff + rs.dt - r.dt <= 7 and r.val + rs.cumsum < 1200 then r.val+rs.cumsum
                 else 0 end
                ,case when dt_diff + rs.dt - r.dt > 7 then 0 
                 else dt_diff + rs.dt - r.dt end
          from rsum rs
          join rownums r on r.id = rs.id and r.rnum = rs.rnum+1
         ) 
select id,dt,val,case when cumsum = 0 and lag(cumsum,1) over(partition by id order by dt) <= 1200 then val+lag(cumsum,1) over(partition by id order by dt)
                      when cumsum = 0 and lag(cumsum,1) over(partition by id order by dt) > 1200 then val
                 else cumsum end as res
from rsum
order by 1,2
```

- Compute row numbers per user id in the first cte `rownums`.
- Select the first row from the previously defined `rownums` cte as the anchor row and then iterate through the remaining rows, joining with the anchor row and looking one row ahead at a time. `case` expression here checks for the conditions.
- Cumulative sum was set to `0` by the `rsum` cte, this indicates a new group starts based on either the sum exceeding 1200 within 7 days or a new 7 day period starting. Use `lag` to finally compute values on those rows.

**[`Sample Demo in SQL Server`](https://rextester.com/PEQHSK49951)**